# window.open not opening link

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to open a new window with a share link using the code below:

```
        $content .= "<div class='container-after-post'>

        <div class='sharing'>
        <a
        href='$sswc_fb_share_link'
        target='popup'
        rel='noopener noreferrer'
        onclick=window.open($sswc_fb_share_link, popup, width=600, height=600);
      >
        <i class='fab fa-facebook-f'></i>
      </a>
        </div>
    </div>"
```

But it gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` whenver I click the link, how do I properly escape the window.open part in my code so it works? Please help!

Comment: use this code instead code, its working fine on my system `<?php
$sswc_fb_share_link = 'https://www.w3schools.com';
$content = "<div class='container-after-post'>

        <div class='sharing'>
        <a
        href='$sswc_fb_share_link'
        target='popup'
        rel='noopener noreferrer'
        onclick=window.open($sswc_fb_share_link, popup, width=600, height=600);
      >
        <i class='fab fa-facebook-f'></i>
      </a>
        </div>
    </div>";
?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
See below code helpful.

$content .="<div class='container-after-post'>

        <div class='sharing'>
        <a
        href='$sswc_fb_share_link'
        target='popup'
        rel='noopener noreferrer'
        onclick=\"window.open('$sswc_fb_share_link', popup, width=600, height=600);\">
        <i class='fab fa-facebook-f'></i>
      </a>
        </div>
    </div>";
```

Comment: It says popup is not defined

Comment: @AmolBorkar set link in $sswc_fb_share_link param.